# Cake\Http\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException Missing or incorrect CSRF cookie type. in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

We've recently upgraded from an old version of CakePHP (3.10) to CakePHP (4.3).
Since then using the CSRF functionality causes the '[Cake\Http\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException] Missing or incorrect CSRF cookie type.' error.

In the Application.php part of the core we've added;

```
public function middleware($middlewareQueue): \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue
    {
        $middlewareQueue
            // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
            // and make an error page/response
            ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))

            // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
            ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
                'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
            ]))

            // Add routing middleware.
            // Routes collection cache enabled by default, to disable route caching
            // pass null as cacheConfig, example: `new RoutingMiddleware($this)`
            // you might want to disable this cache in case your routing is extremely simple
            ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_'))
            
            // Parse various types of encoded request bodies so that they are
            // available as array through $request->getData()
            // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#body-parser-middleware
            ->add(new BodyParserMiddleware())

            // Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Protection Middleware
            // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/security/csrf.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware
            ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
                'httponly' => false,
            ]));

        return $middlewareQueue;
    }
```

I did some digging and cleaning the cookies works (Client sided) but most of the traffic we get are webhooks from different clients. Is there a way to reset the cookies so that these webhooks can come through without generating the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting this answer verbatim from the CakePHP support Slack, where I saw this question pop up recently:

> you can either add the CSRF middleware to specific routes only: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/security/csrf.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware
>
> or skip the CSRF check for the connected action behind the route: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/security/csrf.html#skipping-csrf-checks-for-specific-actions

(credit: Kevin Pfeifer)